# How do I import the Host directive for Tomcat Server.xml from another file?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

My company wants to be able to add other Hosts directives into our server.xml (configuration file for Tomcat).  This Host directive goes inside the Engine directive.  I will like to import a second file, example hosts.xml, so I can define the hosts in that separate files.

```
<Host name="localhost" ...>
 ...
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
     prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
     pattern="common"/>
 ...
</Host>
```

I have looked into the Professional Apache Tomcat book by WROX ISBN: 0-7645-4372-5 and there was no answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You do that by placing context xml files in the appropriate place:

```
${catalina.home}/conf/Catalina/www.example.com/ROOT.xml
${catalina.home}/conf/Catalina/www.foobar.com/ROOT.xml
${catalina.home}/conf/Catalina/www.foobar.com/other-webapp.xml
```

Unfortunately your server.xml will still have to contain the root host elements:

```
<Engine defaultHost="www.example.com" name="Catalina">
  <Host name="www.example.com"></Host>
  <Host name="www.foobar.com"></Host>
  ...
```

Comment: You have to create the directories under conf/ as well as the context xml files.  See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html, sections "Automatic Application Deployment".